# how to get the match strings(either special characters(like +-=.etc) or string(a-z letters) on the given values.

Tags: java

i have here a pure java code, this one gives me an output of "Special Characters are: java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=[\p{Punct}&&[^_]]+ region=0,8 lastmatch=&&=+-]" as i compile & run, but i want only to have an output of  "Special Characters are:  &&=+-" based on my given value. and also the same with  strings as "strings are: sam" but dont know how to do this, pls help... i used netbeans ide

```
     import java.util.regex.Matcher;
     import java.util.regex.Pattern;

     class SubstringsOfAString
     {
      public static void main(String args[])
         {

        String sample = "sam&&=+-";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\p{Punct}&&[^_]]+");
         Matcher m = p.matcher(sample);

       boolean b = m.find();

       if(b == true)
       {
         System.out.println("Special Characters are: " + m );

         }

       else {
      System.out.println("Nothing" );
       }

            }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the System.out with

```
         System.out.println("Special Characters are: " + m.group());
```

In your solution, you are printing whole Matcher object, not the match.

Comment: yes... thanks a lot JohnnyO...  i got what i needed... 
but one more thing... what about the strings, how do i should make it to have also an output of "Strings are: sam" based on my given value. what should i insert to my codes...

Comment: You'll need a separate Regular Expression for that